# params being wiped during rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing a test for a controller action and for some reason, `params` is being wiped when it reaches the controller action. Here's what I have:

```
  it 'records the event propertly' do
    post :create, params
  end
```

and the controller action:

```
  def create
    # PARAMS IS NIL HERE
    params = params.permit(:data)
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    ## DO STUFF #
    render status: :ok
  end
```

so the issue is `params` is nil in the action. however, request.params is there and correct.

I added a `before_filter` before that action just to see if the params hash was available and it was. so there's something about it going into that action that causes params to wipe.

here's the route: `resources :events, only: :create`

Comment: should it not be `post :create, params: params_hash`?

Comment: @Phil nope, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem ending up being that even though I was putting binding.pry at the top of the controller action, having `params = params.permit(:data)` anywhere in the controller was causing params to be `nil`. Assigning that line to a different variable name than `params` fixed the issue.